# How to calculate FFT of a time series in 3D space (X, Y, T)

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

A time series (x, y, t) in 3D space (X, Y, T) satisfies:

```
x(t) = f1(t), y(t) = f2(t),

where t = 1, 2, 3,....
```

In other words, coordinates (x, y) vary with timestamp t. It is easy to compute the FFT of x(t) or y(t), but how do you calculate the FFT of (x, y)? I assume it should NOT be computed as a 2D-FFT, because that is for an image, whereas (x, y) is just a series. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use

> `fftn`

for example: `Y = fftn(X)` returns the multidimensional Fourier transform of an N-D array using a fast Fourier transform algorithm. The N-D transform is equivalent to computing the 1-D transform along each dimension of X. The output Y is the same size as X.
for 3-D transform:
Create a 3-D signal X. The size of X is 20-by-20-by-20

```
x = (1:20)';
y = 1:20;
z = reshape(1:20,[1 1 20]);
X = cos(2*pi*0.01*x) + sin(2*pi*0.02*y) + cos(2*pi*0.03*z);
```

Compute the 3-D Fourier transform of the signal, which is also a 20-by-20-by-20 array.

```
Y = fftn(X)
```

Pad X with zeros to compute a 32-by-32-by-32 transform.

```
m = nextpow2(20);
Y = fftn(X,[2^m 2^m 2^m]);
size(Y)
```

**also you can use this code:**
first You might use SINGLE intead of DOUBLE

```
psi = single(psi);
fftpsi = fft(psi,[],3);
```

Next might be working slide by slide

```
psi=rand(10,10,10);
% costly way
fftpsi=fftn(psi);
% This might save you some RAM, to be tested
[m,n,p] = size(psi);
for k=1:p
    psi(:,:,k) = fftn(psi(:,:,k)); 
end
psi = reshape(psi,[m*n p]);
for i=1:m*n % you might work on bigger row-block to increase speed
    psi(i,:) = fft(psi(i,:));
end
psi = reshape(psi,[m n p]);
% Check
norm(psi(:)-fftpsi(:))
```

*I hope it will be useful for you*